# an error encountered ORA-08181: specified number is not a valid system change number

Tags: sql, oracle

while i am executing the following query

```
select nam, ORA_ROWSCN,SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN) from cus where sno=7;
```

i got the following error

```
[Error] Execution (13: 24): ORA-08181: specified number is not a valid system change number
ORA-06512: at "SYS.SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP", line 1
```

the table **cus** contains the following data

```
select * from cus;

   SNO NAM        GENDER     SALARY        AGE
------ ---------- ------ ---------- ----------
     1 durgesh    m           50000         21
     2 jagadeesh  m           45000         19
     3 sania      f           30000         22
     4 sukhanya   f           12000         22
     5 pallavi    f           15000         20
     6 maneendra  m           25000         23
     7 sree veena f           17500         22
     8 divya      f           17800         23
```

can anyone explain why the select statement shows that error

thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681705/how-to-use-timestamp-to-scn-and-scn-to-timestamp-in-oracle

Comment: you have `FLASHBACK` enabled?

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar
`select flashback_archive_name,status from   dba_flashback_archive;
select * from dba_flashback_archive;
SELECT flashback_on FROM v$database;` 
when i am executing the above queries error was encountered resulting **table or view doesn't exit**

Comment: @Smart003 - you'd need to run those queries from an account with suitable privileges; or ask your DBA. But the question user1933888 linked to explains the issue, at least some of the rows in the table were last updated outside your undo/flashback window.