# SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP (Max(ora_rowscn)) to create a new modified table for a list of tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 5 tables which I want to compare the DLL date against the Max(ora_rowscn).

```
 select owner, object_name, LAST_DDL_TIME from dba_objects;
 select * from dba_objects
 where object_name in ('Table_1', 'Table_2', 'Table_3', 'Table_4','Table_5')
```

I know I could use a 'with clause' & union all the SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP data to join onto the dba_objects table, but is there a more effective way as in reality I have more than 5 tables.

```
with
table 1 as (SELECT 'table1' as Table,SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP (Max(ora_rowscn)) from table1),
table 2 as (SELECT 'table2' as Table,SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP (Max(ora_rowscn)) from table2),
table 3 as (SELECT 'table3' as Table,SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP (Max(ora_rowscn)) from table3),
....and so on
```

Is there a way I could use the list created in the dba_objects query to use the SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP (Max(ora_rowscn)) for each table name in the list?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dbms_xmlgen.getxml()` to generate a query semi-dynamically. If I create and populate two dummy tables:

create table table_1 (id number);
insert into table_1 values (42);
create table table_2 (id number);
-- wait one second
insert into table_2 values (42);

then I can get the `dba_objects` data and matching `ora_rowscn` value - albeit as XML - in one hit:

```
select owner, object_name, last_ddl_time,
  dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select max(ora_rowscn) as max_ora_rowscn from '
    || object_name) as xml_clob
from dba_objects
where object_type = 'TABLE'
and object_name in ('TABLE_1', 'TABLE_2');

OWNER         OBJECT_NAME          LAST_DDL_ XML_CLOB                                          
------------- -------------------- --------- --------------------------------------------------
MY_SCHEMA     TABLE_2              09-JUN-17 <?xml version="1.0"?>                             
                                             <ROWSET>                                          
                                              <ROW>                                            
                                               <MAX_ORA_ROWSCN>10321138892740</MAX_ORA_ROWSCN> 
                                              </ROW>                                           
                                             </ROWSET>                                         

MY_SCHEMA     TABLE_1              09-JUN-17 <?xml version="1.0"?>                             
                                             <ROWSET>                                          
                                              <ROW>                                            
                                               <MAX_ORA_ROWSCN>10321138892720</MAX_ORA_ROWSCN> 
                                              </ROW>                                           
                                             </ROWSET>
```

Which doesn't immediately look all that useful, but you can then use more XML DB functionality to extract the actual number you want:

```
with cte as (
  select owner, object_name, last_ddl_time,
    dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select max(ora_rowscn) as max_ora_rowscn from '
      || object_name) as xml_clob
  from dba_objects
  where object_type = 'TABLE'
  and object_name in ('TABLE_1', 'TABLE_2')
)
select cte.owner, cte.object_name,
    to_char(cte.last_ddl_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as last_ddl_time,
    x.max_ora_rowscn,
    to_char(scn_to_timestamp(x.max_ora_rowscn), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as max_scn_timestamp
from cte
cross join xmltable('/ROWSET/ROW'
  passing xmltype(cte.xml_clob)
  columns max_ora_rowscn number path 'MAX_ORA_ROWSCN'
) x;

OWNER         OBJECT_NAME          LAST_DDL_TIME       MAX_ORA_ROWSCN MAX_SCN_TIMESTAMP  
------------- -------------------- ------------------- -------------- -------------------
MY_SCHEMA     TABLE_1              2017-06-09 13:46:46     1.0321E+13 2017-06-09 13:46:44
MY_SCHEMA     TABLE_2              2017-06-09 13:46:46     1.0321E+13 2017-06-09 13:46:47
```

But you have a couple of problems with what you're doing. Firstly notice that the DDL time is shown as the same for both tables, and the `ora_rowscn` looks sensible for `table_1`; but for `table_2` it appears to be before the table was even created. That's down to how SCNs work really.

The bigger problem is you're [limited in how far you can look back](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22681857/266304); if the table's maximum `ora_rowsn` is outside your database's redo/flashback retention period then trying to convert it will fail.

It's possible everything you're looking at is recent enough - you haven't said *why* you're doing this - and you could potentially choose not to attempt to convert `ora_rowscn` values that are too old, which you could find form elsewhere in the data dictionary. That might make your whole exercise pointless though. You also may need to deal with empty tables, where `max(ora_rowscn)` will be null, causing `scn_to_timestamp()` to fail.