# How to find Row Creation Date and Time in db table

Tags: oracle

Is it possible to find the date when a particular row was created in table in an Oracle database . ***(without insertion of creation date time in a column).***

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, It is actually possible. You may want to check answers for this. If you have any comment which we don't know please drop a comment. thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can use ORA_ROWSCN pseudocolumn in your query. Look:

```
SELECT SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN), last_name FROM employees
WHERE employee_id = 188;
```

Please also review the docs about this: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns007.htm

Comment: As per doc 'This pseudocolumn is useful for determining approximately when a row was last updated.'

Comment: You can only also convert the SCN to a timestamp for a limited time - [after that you'll get ORA-08181](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22681705/266304). And depending on how the table was created it may be when the *block* was last updated, not necessarily a specific *row* (as the doc you kinked to says).

Comment: @Alex Pool : Yes I have tried for some SCNs, some of them giving _ORA-08181: specified number is not a valid system change number_

Answer (score 0):

If the journaling / Auditing for Insert is enabled on your Oracle RDBMS, yes it is possible to do so.

```
AUDIT INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON MySchema.MyTable BY ACCESS;
```

Then to audit logs are started to get logged. After this moment you can query it from

```
select * from sys.aud$
```

Comment: Note that this requires an enterprise edition if I'm not mistaken. And it will not show the information for rows created before auditing was enabled.

Answer (score 0):

For example 1. Insert. Using Flashback Features.

```
insert into test2(p1,p2,p3)
values(1,'test_insert','test')
==>
1 row(s) inserted

SELECT versions_xid XID, versions_startscn START_SCN,    
      versions_endscn END_SCN, versions_operation OPERATION,
       p1, p2, p3, ROWIDTOCHAR(ROWID) 
FROM manager.test2
    VERSIONS BETWEEN SCN MINVALUE AND MAXVALUE;
XID, START_SCN, END_SCN, OPERATION,  p1, p2, p3,      ROWIDTOCHAR(ROWID)
04000A0054FD0A00    1404377619968       I   1   test_insert     test    AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAO
                                            22                          AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAA
                                            24                          AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAB
                                            54                          AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAC
                                            10                          AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAD
                                            10  test2 test1             AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAE
                                            225 test10                  AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAF
                                            225 test10                  AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAG
                                            225 test10                  AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAH
                                            225 test10                  AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAI
                                            225 test10                  AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAJ
                                            225 test10                  AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAK
                                            225 test10          test4   AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAL
                                            225 test10          test4   AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAM
                                            50  test insert     test    AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAN


SQL> SELECT SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP('1404377619968') FROM dual;

SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP('1404377619968')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
25.01.19 07:32:12,000000000


SELECT SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN),p1,p2,p3 FROM test2

25.01.19 07:32:12,000000000 22                  
25.01.19 07:32:12,000000000 24                  
25.01.19 07:32:12,000000000 54                  
25.01.19 07:32:12,000000000 10                  
25.01.19 07:32:12,000000000 10  test2 test1     
25.01.19 07:32:12,000000000 225 test10          
25.01.19 07:32:12,000000000 225 test10          
25.01.19 07:32:12,000000000 225 test10          
25.01.19 07:32:12,000000000 225 test10          
25.01.19 07:32:12,000000000 225 test10          
25.01.19 07:32:12,000000000 225 test10          
25.01.19 07:32:12,000000000 225 test10          test4 
25.01.19 07:32:12,000000000 225 test10          test4 
25.01.19 07:32:12,000000000 50  test insert     test
25.01.19 07:32:12,000000000 1   test_insert     test
```

For example 2.Update. Using Flashback Features.

```
CREATE TABLE manager.test2
    (p1                             NUMBER,
    p2                             VARCHAR2(200 BYTE),
    p3                             VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)
    )


select * from test2;
p1            p2                 p3
---------- --------------- --------
22                  
24                  
54                  
124                 
124 test2 test1     
225 test10          
225 test10          
225 test10          
225 test10          
225 test10          
225 test10          
225 test10          test4 
225 test10          test4 


update test2 set p1=10 where p1=124
==>
2 row(s) updated





    SELECT versions_xid XID, versions_startscn START_SCN,    
      versions_endscn END_SCN, versions_operation OPERATION,
       p1, p2, p3, ROWIDTOCHAR(ROWID) 
FROM manager.test2
    VERSIONS BETWEEN SCN MINVALUE AND MAXVALUE;


XID,                               START_SCN,    END_SCN,  OPERATION,  p1,           p2,          p3,          ROWIDTOCHAR(ROWID)

07000F0051030B00    1404163252291                   U   10  test2            test1          AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAE
07000F0051030B00    1404163252291                   U   10                      AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAD
                                                                22                          AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAA
                                                                24                          AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAB
                                                                54                          AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAC
                                                 1404163252291  124                         AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAD
                                                 1404163252291  124 test2 test1         AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAE
                                                                225 test10                  AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAF
                                                                225 test10                  AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAG
                                                                225 test10                  AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAH
                                                                225 test10                  AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAI
                                                                225 test10                  AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAJ
                                                                225 test10                  AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAK
                                                                225 test10          test4   AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAL
                                                                225 test10          test4   AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAM




 SQL> SELECT SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP('1404163252291') FROM dual;

        SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP('1404163252291')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        24.01.19 14:08:27,000000000

    SELECT  xid, start_scn , commit_scn COMMIT,operation OP, logon_user ,undo_sql FROM flashback_transaction_query
    WHERE xid = HEXTORAW('07000F0051030B00');


    07000F0051030B00    1404163252288   1404163252291   UPDATE  MANAGER update "MANAGER"."TEST2" set "P1" = '124' where ROWID = 'AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAE';
    07000F0051030B00    1404163252288   1404163252291   UPDATE  MANAGER update "MANAGER"."TEST2" set "P1" = '124' where ROWID = 'AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAD';
    07000F0051030B00    1404163252288   1404163252291   BEGIN   MANAGER
```