# Exception : ORA-08181 : specified number is not a valid system change number

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle19c

I have a table which is throwing error for some of the rows when try to convert
ORA_ROWSCN for corresponding row to SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP as below:-

```
Select SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(429804070) from dual; --14-NOV-22 07.52.22.000000000 AM
Select SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(432572474) from dual; --16-NOV-22 02.00.59.000000000 AM
Select SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(423859441) from dual; --ORA-08181: specified number is not a valid system change number
Select SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(423859575) from dual; --ORA-08181: specified number is not a valid system change number
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Kindly someone explain and provide the solution.

Comment: [Related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22681705/266304)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're *out of range*.

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
```

Let's check the range first:

```
SQL> select min(scn), max(scn) from sys.smon_scn_time;

  MIN(SCN)   MAX(SCN)
---------- ----------
  14831895   16817322
```

Apply `scn_to_timestamp` to MIN and MAX values - both of them are *valid*:

```
SQL> select SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(14831895) min_scn,
  2         SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(16817322) max_scn
  3  from dual;

MIN_SCN                          MAX_SCN
-------------------------------- --------------------------------
08-OCT-22 10.23.31.000000000 PM  19-NOV-22 10.11.36.000000000 PM
```

What if you try values that are out of that range (i.e. lower than MIN and higher than MAX)? None of them work, and that's your case:

```
SQL> select SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(10831895) lower_than_min_scn from dual;
select SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(10831895) lower_than_min_scn from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-08181: specified number is not a valid system change number
ORA-06512: at "SYS.SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP", line 1


SQL> Select SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(19817322) higher_than_max_scn from dual;
Select SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(19817322) higher_than_max_scn from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-08181: specified number is not a valid system change number
ORA-06512: at "SYS.SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP", line 1


SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you @Littlefoot. Can we increase the smon_scn_time somehow to accommodate the out of range scn number. Sorry I am new to oracle and just exploring possibilities

Comment: SCN changes with every commit, Oracle increments it itself. I don't think that you can set it yourself.

Comment: BEFORE: SQL> select min(scn), max(scn) from smon_scn_time; AFTER: SQL> select min(scn), max(scn) from sys.smon_scn_time;

(I am responsible for the edit)